# Сохранить массив изображений на сервер node

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, promise

Имеется массив с информацией о группах вк. В том числе и изображения. Суть заключается в необходимости поочередно записать их на сервер для дальнейшего отображения. Понятное дело нужны промисы, но я не до конца улавливаю их суть. Ниже привожу участок кода

```js
var saveImg = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request.get({
      url: url,
      encoding: 'binary'
    }, function(err, response, body) {

      fs.writeFile('test.jpg', body, 'binary', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });

  });
};

request(urlRender.reqVk("groups.get", user, token, "&filter=admin&extended=1"), function(error, response, body) {
  var groupJSON = JSON.parse(body);

  var groups = groupJSON['response']['items'];
  console.log("groups", groups[0]);

  for (var i = 0; i <= groups.length - 1; i++) {

    saveImg(groups[i]['photo_200']).then(function() {
        console.log("Img is on server");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("something wrong with saving img", err);
      });
  }
});

if (err) {
  console.log(err)
}

});
```

При этом коде записывает или 6 или 8 изображение. Я так понимаю, здесь нужен promise.all, но не догоняю, как реализовать. Помогите плез

Comment: Ну, для начала, вы пытаетесь все изображения записать в один и тот же файл test.jpg. Надо каждому уникальное имя сделать, чтобы они друг друга не затирали

Comment: @Darth, Спасибо большое)) Все работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

```js
var saveImg = function(url, i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request.get({
      url: url,
      encoding: 'binary'
    }, function(err, response, body) {

      fs.writeFile('test' + i + '.jpg', body, 'binary', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });

  });
};

request(urlRender.reqVk("groups.get", user, token, "&filter=admin&extended=1"), function(error, response, body) {
  var groupJSON = JSON.parse(body);

  var groups = groupJSON['response']['items'];
  console.log("groups", groups[0]);

  for (var i = 0; i <= groups.length - 1; i++) {

    saveImg(groups[i]['photo_200'], i).then(function() {
        console.log("Img is on server");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("something wrong with saving img", err);
      });

    console.log(i + " group name: ", groups[i]['name']);

  }


});

if (err) {
  console.log(err)
}

});
```